# Best method for caching repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-web-api, httpcontext

I have MVC 4 Web-application, which contains an API Controller for CRUD operations against a data source. To simplify what im try to do, I'll use a movie repository as example. Data source contains one Class, called MovieData(Title,Genre,MovieId etc), which methods GetAllMovies, Update, Create,GetMovieByid. Calling the data source is costly, so I want to impement some sort of caching, espesially on the retrieval of the movie list. Updating the original data source is done daily, and only once.

What would be the best way to implement this? Should I use HTTPContext.Current.Cache for this, or is there another (better) way?

```
public class MovieController : ApiController
{
    private const string CacheKey = "MovieStore";
    private MovieDataSource movieRepository;

    public MovieController()
    {
        //this.movieRepository = new MovieDataSource();

        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        if (ctx != null)
        {
            if (ctx.Cache[CacheKey] == null)
            {
                this.movieRepository = new MovieDataSource();
                ctx.Cache[CacheKey] = movieRepository;
            }
        }
    }}
```

Or should I simply call the movieRepository.GetAllMovies, create a new list, all all the movies to that list, and then perform all CRUD operations against that list. And then at the end of the day, update the data source with the cached list I created? This should be very simple to do, I'm just trying to find the "best practice" way to implement this in MVC 4.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against maintaining your own list in memory for a few reasons.

One, it may make things like Foreign Keys very difficult to deal with if you are using any. IE. you would have to get the write insert order at the end of the day to avoid errors.

Two, you will be loading potentially large amounts of data all into the system. The advantage of the way you have currently implemented it is that the data is loaded only when it is needed, rather than loading everything in at once and hogging potentially large volumes of memory.

And most importantly, what happens in this scenario if you have a server crash? or if the web app is recycled? If you are waiting to write your list to a data source and all of a sudden one of these happens, you will lose all your data with no way of recovering it.

HTTPContext.Current.Cache seems to be a valid method for doing this, but you could always investigate ObjectCache as well.

Also, when dealing with Caching, remember to update or flush the object from the cache if and when you update or delete it!